# How to show two  values in a single textview on different lines

Tags: android, textview

How do you show two values on different lines using a single `testview`? I can get this by using two textviews but I want to show values in a single `textview`. What should I d0?

```
 xmlRespone[3][1]= Salman Ahmed
 xmlRespone[4][1]= 435000;

TextView lblWelcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblWelcome);
            lblWelcome.setText("Welcome " + xmlRespone[3][1]);


            TextView lblYouraccountbalance = (TextView)  
   findViewById(R.id.lblYouraccountbalance);
            lblYouraccountbalance.setText(" balance :" + xmlRespone[4][1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try "\n" for new line.

```
TextView lblWelcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblWelcome);
lblWelcome.setText("Welcome " + xmlRespone[3][1] + "\n" + xmlRespone[4][1]);

Output  : Welcome Salman Ahmed
          435000
```

Comment: @Hayya Anam : if get solution then you can accept answer. Other wise post comment here

Comment: how i change 2nd line text color diffrent??

Comment: its work fine thnx but both text are same color how i chnage text color change both of them???
"\n" + xmlRespone[4][1]  after new line how i change text color?

Comment: @HayyaAnam For that you need to take different Textview . You can not do it with single textview.